# Fitting regression model calculation in r

Tags: r

I am working on a problem to fit a regression model and calculate the error rate of my data. I had an error message below:

Error in performance(prediction(inpPred, inpTruth), measure = metrTmp) :
could not find function "performance"

Here is my reproducible code

```
wifiDat <- read.table("wifi_localization.txt",sep="\t")
colnames(wifiDat) <- c("WF1", "WF2", "WF3", "WF4", "WF5", "WF6", "WF7", "RM")
wifiDat$RM <- factor(wifiDat$RM)
dim(wifiDat)
summary(wifiDat)
head(wifiDat)
ggpairs(wifiDat,aes(colour=RM))
glm.fit <- glm(RM~WF1+WF2+WF3+WF4+WF5+WF6+WF7,data=wifiDat,family=binomial)
glmPred <- predict(glm.fit,type="response")>0.5
table(wifiDat[,"RM"],glmPred)
SummPreds <- function(inpPred,inpTruth,inpMetrNms=c("err","acc","sens","spec")) {
retVals <- numeric()
for ( metrTmp in inpMetrNms ) {
retVals[metrTmp] <- performance(prediction(inpPred,inpTruth),measure=metrTmp)@y.values[[1]]   [2]
}
retVals
```

}
SummPreds(as.numeric(1+glmPred),as.numeric(wifiDat[,"RM"]))

Here is my sample data

V1. V2. V3. V4. V5. V6. V7. V8
-64 -56 -61 -66 -71 -82 -81 1
-68 -57 -61 -65 -71 -85 -85 2
-63 -60 -60 -67 -76 -85 -84 3
-61 -60 -68 -62 -77 -90 -80 4
-63 -65 -60 -63 -77 -81 -87 1
-64 -55 -63 -66 -76 -88 -83 1
-65 -61 -65 -67 -69 -87 -84 2
-61 -63 -58 -66 -74 -87 -82 3
-65 -60 -59 -63 -76 -86 -82 4
-62 -60 -66 -68 -80 -86 -91 1
-67 -61 -62 -67 -77 -83 -91 1
-65 -59 -61 -67 -72 -86 -81 1
-63 -57 -61 -65 -73 -84 -84 1

Please what am I doing wrong?

Comment: In your code, the function `performance` is not defined. Is this a custom function, or a function that is defined within another library?

Comment: (copied from @jmogil's non-answer): In your code, the function `performance` is not defined. Is this a custom function, or a function that is defined within another package?

Comment: It's a custom function. Is there another way to do the calculation without using the function?

Comment: You're more or less telling us "my code needs a custom function but according to R it hasn't been defined".  That leaves us doing guesswork. Where is it supposed to come from? Is there a file you're supposed to `source()` (i.e., read into R to define the functions?)

Comment: I just need to write a code(function), that will calculate "err","acc","sens","spec".

Comment: Are you sure you're not talking about `https://rdrr.io/cran/mlr/man/performance.html` ? Try `install.packages("mlr"); library(mlr)`